# pcap.net mac address setting

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I'm setting up a program to send a UDP packet from one server to another on a different network. I'm having trouble setting up the EthernetLayer, I've managed to set the source MacAddress to my own using:

```
    public static string GetMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddresses = string.Empty;

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                //macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress();
                macAddresses = string.Join(":", (from z in nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes() select z.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
                break;
            }
        }

        return macAddresses;
    }
```

This seems to work fine, however what do I set as the Destination MacAddress? No matter what I set it to, it seems to just be broadcasting the packet across my local network to all machines. This is the code below that I followed from the pcapdotnet example.

```
        new EthernetLayer
        {
            Source = new MacAddress(Mac),
            Destination = new MacAddress("02:02:02:02:02:02"),
            EtherType = EthernetType.None,
        };
```

This correctly sets my source MacAddress but the destination is obviously incorrect, the example on pcapdotnets document looks as follows:

```
        new EthernetLayer
            {
                Source = new MacAddress("01:01:01:01:01:01"),
                Destination = new MacAddress("02:02:02:02:02:02"),
                EtherType = EthernetType.None, // Will be filled automatically.
            };
```

Is there a way of getting the MacAddress of the destination IP?

Comment: You're looking for Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) which will map an IP address to a MAC address

Comment: This is what [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) accomplishes automatically. It resolves the MAC address for an IP address.  If you aren't familiar with how this works, why are you creating packets from the MAC layer?  If you just want to send a UDP packet, there are much simpler ways to do so.

Comment: Using Pcap.net or something else? I got pretty lost in their documentation so that's why I'm now stuck here

Comment: More to the point though, if the destination is on a different network and the only address you have is the MAC, chances are the packet will never arrive, unless you have something other than a router between the two.  If you send an ARP packet and the destination isn't in your broadcast domain, the MAC address you get in response may be that of a router.  Or else your stack will just look in the routing path and pass it directly to the appropriate router.

Comment: All I have is the destination IP, not the MAC. I'm just in need of sending a UDP packet with a custom payload and source IP as my server listens for player connections. Using straight UDPClient in C# wasn't enough because I couldn't change the source IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the ARP protocol to automatically get the MAC address of an IP address. To use it, first read about ARP and get familiar with it and then see the `ArpLayer` and `ArpDatagram` in [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdot.net).

If you want to skip over that step, you can just check what is your router MAC address and simply write it hard-coded, since it won't change unless you use a different router.